# Asterisk - music on hold

Tags: asterisk, repeat

I want to randomly pick a wav file I have as MUSICONHOLD and i want it to continuously repeat that same file until the caller hang up.... right now, I have 10 files in the musiconhold folder, and it seems to randomly play one file after the other...

Any kind of insight on this is greatly appreciated!

Here's what I have now:

```
exten => _18X.,1,Set(TIMEOUT(absolute)=${RAND(60,345)})
exten => _18X.,2,Answer
exten => _18X.,3,MusicOnHold
exten => _18X.,4,Hangup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create 10 musiconhold classes and select one using something like this:

```
exten => _18X.,3,MusicOnHold(class${RAND(0,10)});
```